# Preserve row order of rhandsontable in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am running an example from [here](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/tree/master/inst/examples/rhandsontable_datafile).

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("hot")),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    fname <- "mtcars2.csv"
    values <- reactiveValues()
    setHot <- function(x) values[["hot"]] = x

    observe({
      if(!is.null(values[["hot"]])) write.csv(values[["hot"]], fname)
    })

    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
      if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
        DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
      } else {
        DF <- read.csv("mtcars.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      }
      setHot(DF)
      rhandsontable(DF) %>%
        hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
        hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE)
    })
  }
))
```

I want changes made to table be saved in file `mtcars2.csv`. I also want to preserve row order. In [project home page](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#sorting) it says "sorting only impacts the widget and will not reorder the original data set". Can I somehow get current view of a table and save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to answer this question will be to file an issue at https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable.  Currently, these [lines](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/rhandsontable.js#L67-L173) define only a partial list of `handsontable` events.  This list does not include `afterColumnSort` which would be what you need.  Here is a quick hack to partially answer your question.

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
    tags$script(
'
setTimeout(
  function() {
    HTMLWidgets.find("#hot").hot.addHook(
      "afterColumnSort",
      function(){
        console.log("sort",this);
        Shiny.onInputChange(
          "hot_sort",
          {
            data: this.getData()
          }
        )
      }
    )
  },
  1000
)
' 

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(
      input$hot_sort
      ,{
        print(input$hot_sort$data)
      }
    )

    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
      if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
        DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
      } else {
        DF <- mtcars
      }
      rhandsontable(DF) %>%
        hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
        hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE)
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to preserve the sorted columns in DataTables for shiny, Sad!

With the below code I'm able to save changes made in shiny app to the file `mtcars2.csv`. Interestingly! post sorting by desired column, clicking on any data cell and pressing enter key saves the row order to the `mtcars2.csv`. Agree with `timelyportolio`'s point on filing an issue on git.

#### R Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(titlePanel("Edit Data File"),
                 helpText("Changes to the table will be automatically saved to the source file."),
             # actionButton("saveBtn", "Save"),
             rHandsontableOutput("hot")),
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  values = reactiveValues()
  data = reactive({
    if (is.null(input$hot)) {
      hot = read.csv("mtcars.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     } else {
      hot = hot_to_r(input$hot)
    }

    # this would be used as a function input
    values[["hot"]] = hot
    hot
  })

  observe({
    # input$saveBtn
    if (!is.null(values[["hot"]])) {
      write.csv(values[["hot"]], "mtcars.csv", row.names = FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    hot = data()
    if (!is.null(hot)) {
      hot = rhandsontable(hot) %>%
        hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
        hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE)
      hot
    }
  })
})
))
```